# Why getSelectedRow( ) method don't return the index of the selected row?

Tags: java, swing

I use the method `getSelectedRow()` to get the index of the selected row in the first table. When I use it again to get the index of the selected row in the second table it still returns the index of the selected row in the first table. I can't figure out why!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Selection extends JFrame {

    int row;
    String actualArray;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
    DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
    DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table1 = new JTable(model1);
    JTable table2 = new JTable(model2);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
    JButton showSelectedRow = new JButton("Show");
    JButton switchTable = new JButton("switch");
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    String [] columns = {"ID","Name"};
    String [][] array1 = {{"0001","Alice"},{"0002","Evanka"},{"0003","Steve"}};
    String [][] array2 = {{"0004","David"},{"0005","Mario"},{"0006","Marry"}};

    public Selection() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Selection();
            }
        });

    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        model1.setDataVector(array1,columns);
        model2.setDataVector(array2,columns);
        panel.setBounds(15,20,500,480);
        scrollPane1.setBounds(20,25,50,50);
        scrollPane2.setBounds(20,25,50,50);
        showSelectedRow.setBounds(40,160,60,25);
        switchTable.setBounds(120,160,60,25);
        actions();
        panel.add(scrollPane1);
        actualArray="array1";
        panel.add(showSelectedRow);
        panel.add(switchTable);
        add(panel);
        setSize(550, 500);
        setLocation(230, 70);
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void actions() {
        showSelectedRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (actualArray.equals("array1")) {
                       row =table1.getSelectedRow();
                    } else {
                       row =table2.getSelectedRow();
                    }
                    showDialog();
            }
        });
        switchTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (actualArray.equals("array1")) {
                    panel.removeAll();
                    panel.add(scrollPane1);
                    actualArray = "array2";
                    panel.add(showSelectedRow);
                    panel.add(switchTable);
                    add(panel);
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    panel.removeAll();
                    panel.add(scrollPane2);
                    actualArray = "array1";
                    panel.add(showSelectedRow);
                    panel.add(switchTable);
                    add(panel);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });

    }
        private void showDialog() {
            dialogPanel.setBounds(5,5,50,30);
            label.setText(String.valueOf(row));
            label.setBounds(10,10,180,20);
            dialogPanel.add(label);
            dialog.add(dialogPanel);
            dialog.setSize(60, 50);
            dialog.setLocation(450, 250);
            dialog.setLayout(null);
            dialog.setResizable(false);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't switch the physical tables, switch the models - problem will be solved

Comment: Do you suggest to use one JTable and one scrollPane but two models and passing one of them every time i want to show the appropriate table ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, also, your `null` layout broke on my system

Comment: I will try to fix that . Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic is backwards here...

When `actualArray` equals `"array1"`, you're adding `scrollPane1` and setting `actualArray` to `"array2`" ... shouldn't you be adding `scrollPane2`?

```
if (actualArray.equals("array1")) {
    panel.removeAll();
    panel.add(scrollPane1);
    actualArray = "array2";
    panel.add(showSelectedRow);
    panel.add(switchTable);
    add(panel);
    repaint();
} else {
    panel.removeAll();
    panel.add(scrollPane2);
    actualArray = "array1";
    panel.add(showSelectedRow);
    panel.add(switchTable);
    add(panel);
    repaint();
}
```

Having said that, I "accidentally" fixed you code trying to repair the `null` layout issues.

This example makes use of a `CardLayout` to switch between the tables instead...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class FixMe extends JFrame {

    int row;
    String actualArray;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
    DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
    DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table1 = new JTable(model1);
    JTable table2 = new JTable(model2);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
    JButton showSelectedRow = new JButton("Show");
    JButton switchTable = new JButton("switch");
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    String[] columns = {"ID", "Name"};
    String[][] array1 = {{"0001", "Alice"}, {"0002", "Evanka"}, {"0003", "Steve"}};
    String[][] array2 = {{"0004", "David"}, {"0005", "Mario"}, {"0006", "Marry"}};

    public FixMe() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FixMe();
            }
        });

    }

    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        dialog.add(label);

        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        panel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        model1.setDataVector(array1, columns);
        model2.setDataVector(array2, columns);
        actions();
        actualArray = "array1";
        panel.add(scrollPane1, "array1");
        panel.add(scrollPane2, "array2");

        JPanel actions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        actions.add(showSelectedRow);
        actions.add(switchTable);

//        panel.add(showSelectedRow);
//        panel.add(switchTable);
        add(panel);
        add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//        setSize(550, 500);
//        setLocation(230, 70);
//        setLayout(null);
//        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void actions() {
        showSelectedRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (actualArray.equals("array1")) {
                    row = table1.getSelectedRow();
                } else {
                    row = table2.getSelectedRow();
                }
                showDialog();
            }
        });
        switchTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (actualArray.equals("array1")) {
//                    panel.removeAll();
//                    panel.add(scrollPane1);
                    actualArray = "array2";
                    cardLayout.show(panel, actualArray);
//                    panel.add(showSelectedRow);
//                    panel.add(switchTable);
//                    add(panel);
//                    repaint();
                } else {
//                    panel.removeAll();
//                    panel.add(scrollPane2);
                    actualArray = "array1";
                    cardLayout.show(panel, actualArray);
//                    panel.add(showSelectedRow);
//                    panel.add(switchTable);
//                    add(panel);
//                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void showDialog() {
        label.setText(String.valueOf(row));
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(panel);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
//        label.setBounds(10, 10, 180, 20);
//        dialogPanel.add(label);
//        dialog.add(dialogPanel);
//        dialog.setSize(60, 50);
//        dialog.setLocation(450, 250);
//        dialog.setLayout(null);
//        dialog.setResizable(false);
//        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
//        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I recommend having a read through of [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Now, having said all that, I would recommend just switching the models...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String[] columns = {"ID", "Name"};
                String[][] array1 = {{"0001", "Alice"}, {"0002", "Evanka"}, {"0003", "Steve"}};
                String[][] array2 = {{"0004", "David"}, {"0005", "Mario"}, {"0006", "Marry"}};

                TableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(array1, columns);
                TableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(array2, columns);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane(new TableModel[]{model1, model2}));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private TableModel[] models;
        private int currentModel = 0;
        private JLabel selectedRowLabel;

        public TestPane(TableModel[] models) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            table = new JTable();

            this.models = models;
            table.setModel(models[0]);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            selectedRowLabel = new JLabel("...");

            JButton switchButton = new JButton("Switch");
            switchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    currentModel += 1;
                    if (currentModel >= models.length) {
                        currentModel = 0;
                    }
                    table.setModel(models[currentModel]);
                    updateSelectionInformation();
                }
            });

            JPanel infoPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            infoPane.add(switchButton);
            infoPane.add(selectedRowLabel);

            add(infoPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    updateSelectionInformation();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void updateSelectionInformation() {
            if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
                selectedRowLabel.setText(Integer.toString(table.getSelectedRow()));
            } else {
                selectedRowLabel.setText("---");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now, if the previously selected row is important, simply keep track of it when you switch and re-apply it, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String[] columns = {"ID", "Name"};
                String[][] array1 = {{"0001", "Alice"}, {"0002", "Evanka"}, {"0003", "Steve"}};
                String[][] array2 = {{"0004", "David"}, {"0005", "Mario"}, {"0006", "Marry"}};

                TableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(array1, columns);
                TableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(array2, columns);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane(new TableModel[]{model1, model2}));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private TableModel[] models;
        private int[] lastSelectedRow;
        private int currentModel = 0;
        private JLabel selectedRowLabel;

        public TestPane(TableModel[] models) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            table = new JTable();

            lastSelectedRow = new int[models.length];
            Arrays.fill(lastSelectedRow, -1);

            this.models = models;
            table.setModel(models[0]);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            selectedRowLabel = new JLabel("...");

            JButton switchButton = new JButton("Switch");
            switchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    lastSelectedRow[currentModel] = table.getSelectedRow();
                    currentModel += 1;
                    if (currentModel >= models.length) {
                        currentModel = 0;
                    }
                    table.setModel(models[currentModel]);
                    if (lastSelectedRow[currentModel] > -1) {
                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(lastSelectedRow[currentModel], lastSelectedRow[currentModel]);
                    }
                    updateSelectionInformation();
                }
            });

            JPanel infoPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            infoPane.add(switchButton);
            infoPane.add(selectedRowLabel);

            add(infoPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    updateSelectionInformation();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void updateSelectionInformation() {
            if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
                selectedRowLabel.setText(Integer.toString(table.getSelectedRow()));
            } else {
                selectedRowLabel.setText("---");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ActuallyThis is very helpful. thank you so much .

Comment: Actually  when actualArray equals "array1" its like a flag that the next press on switch will lead to showing the first table so im adding scrollPane1 and setting actualArray to "array2" to indicate that the next press on switch will lead to show the second table this time. Your answer is very helpful. thank you so much .

Comment: @taherbouali Yes, but when you inspect the selected row you're using `actualArray`, which is set to `array2` when the table for `array1` is been displayed - I understand there use, but you've mixed them up

Comment: it's very clear that your code is more efficient and convincing than mine but but I still wonder if there is a way to solve the problem without changing the way i used to organise the components that will be shown on the frame i mean making the layout null, adding the scrollpanes and the buttons to the panel and then adding the panel to the JFrame instance.

Comment: `null` layout, or pixel perfect layouts, are an illusion.  There are so many factors involved in calculating the size, positions and relationships of components that university professors make livings out of coming up with algorithms  and mathematical models to solve it (no, seriously, they do).  Instead, take the time to learn and understand how to use the layout management API. As some who once did working in VB, I can tell you, the layout management API is a god send.  The first example, using `CardLayout` is the closes to your original

Comment: Im new in java and that's why i don't have a good understanding of layout management yet. Thank you again :)